# RavenDB 4+ paged query with distinct on field

Tags: ravendb, paging

I've both client and server at version 4.2.0.

My "Product" document is something like:

```
{
    "Id": 2
    "AggregatedId": 1,
    // Other fields for filters
}
```

Where the aggregated Id is a field on which I'm performing a distinct: I want to retrieve the paged distinc AggregatedId matching certain conditions.

The index I'm using is **NOT** a fanout index, is a normal map index with the only characteristic to have:

```
Store("AggregatedId", FieldStorage.Yes);
```

and as explained in the [Raven documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/indexes/querying/paging#paging-through-tampered-results), until the field I'm applying the distinct to is stored, I should be able to perform the pagination without using the SkippedResults information.

I can query the first page without problem, but when I ask for the second page and upper, I start to notice that the results I'm getting include certain results that were already on the first page. Also the number of results are not correct, I'm getting more rows than expected (eg. 32 items matching a filter, paged by 25, still I'm getting 25 items in the first AND second page...).

The queries I'm building are roughly something like:

```
var res = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Products_ByIndex.ReduceResult, Products_ByIndex>()
                    .WhereEquals("CategoryId", 1)
                    .WhereEquals("BrandId", 478)
                    .OrderBy("AggregatedId")
                    .Statistics(out QueryStatistics stats)
                    .Skip(25)
                    .Take(25)
                    .SelectFields<Products_ByIndex.ReduceResult>("AggregatedId").Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

Am I missing something?